# hashchange event not triggered in IE10 & IE11 with combo of history.pushState and url manual manipulation

Tags: internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, hashchange

I'm having trouble getting the hashchange event to trigger consistently in IE10 and IE11

If I use history.pushState to alter the current hash and then manipulate the hash in the url, then hashchange will be triggered once.

Then if the above is repeated the hashchange is not triggered

I've created a jsbin for testing this issue.
To replicate the issue in IE10/IE11, simply click on a section link (e.g. section 4) and then manipulate the section id in the url (e.g. section-3). A hashchange should be triggered but if you repeat, the second time it won't.

http://jsbin.com/locor/5

BTW - this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Could you add your source code? I will help people diagnose the problem

Comment: Same issue, seems to be a bug with IE11 (haven't tested on IE10), and I haven't managed to find a proper workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Have a repro below. Seems that if you change the hash with pushState IE ignores that change when checking for hashchange events. So if the sequence of your hashes is:

1. #
2. #foo (added via pushstate)
3. # (manually added to address bar)

IE compares #3 against #1 instead #2. Since #1 === #3, IE does not fire a hashchange event.

```
<script>
function log(message) {
    var div = document.getElementById("log");
    div.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
}
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    log("hashchange");
});
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(){
    log("popstate");
});
</script>
<p>1. Manually set the hash in the address bar to "#".</p>
<p><a onclick='history.pushState({}, "", "#somePushState");' style="color:blue;">2. Click here to run push state.</a></p>
<p>3. Manually set the hash in the address bar to "#".</p>

<br>
<p>Expected: browser fires hashchange event for #1 and #3. Actual: IE does not fire hashchange event for #3.</p>
<div id="log"><b>Log:</b><br></div>
```

Comment: One would assume that triggering `HashChangeEvent` manually helps, but in IE `window.HashChangeEvent` is false in this very case; later on it will be available, but not during the first load.